# midi keyboard musescore4 - anyone got this working?

Tags: sound, keyboard, alsa

Under Ubuntu 22.04  musescore3 + midi keyboard works fine. With musescore4 I cannot get musescore to recognise the keyboard. Is there anything I need to enable or install in Ubuntu to make the keyboard work with MS4?
When using MS3, aconnect -i shows:
aconnect -i
client 0: 'System' [type=kernel]
0 'Timer           '
1 'Announce        '
client 14: 'Midi Through' [type=kernel]
0 'Midi Through Port-0'
client 20: 'masterkey 61' [type=kernel,card=1]
0 'masterkey 61 MIDI 1'
client 129: 'MuseScore' [type=user,pid=75509]
2 'MuseScore Port-0'

Under MS4 I see only:
aconnect -i
client 0: 'System' [type=kernel]
0 'Timer           '
1 'Announce        '
client 14: 'Midi Through' [type=kernel]
0 'Midi Through Port-0'
client 20: 'masterkey 61' [type=kernel,card=1]
0 'masterkey 61 MIDI 1'

The are no options in IO preferences under MS4 to select ALSA. Apparently this is automatic.

Richard